# How to select element with multiple exact classes

Tags: jquery

I would like to select following element in DOM to redirect the user to another page if he clicks the button.

```html
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt ph_bookings_book_now_button">Book Now</button>
```

To do so, I use jQuery `jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.ph_bookings_book_now_button").on("click", function() {...}`.

Since I use a plugin, the booking button is visually not active until the user selects a date. The class is then `.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled.ph_bookings_book_now_button` (see additional `disabled`).

To select the button only if the element doesn't contain the class disabled, I've tried the following:

```js
jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.ph_bookings_book_now_button").on("click", function() {
  if(jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled.ph_bookings_book_now_button")) {
    break;
  } else {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
  }
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.
How can I select an element if it contains exactly the classes and nothing more?

Comment: Cant you use ids?

Comment: No, the plugin has only classes. Can I add an ID if the element has certain classes?

Comment: "doesn't work" - please be more specific.  Does it call your click handler?  does it redirect?  does it hit the "break" statement (that does nothing btw)?  Do you need to use event delegation? Have you tried `if ($(this).is(".disabled"))`.  If it really is "disabled" then the click event shouldn't fire - why is it set to disabled when it's shown?   "*until the user selects a date then additional disabled*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the :not selector

```
jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.ph_bookings_book_now_button:not(.disabled)").on("click", function()...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without the 2 classes, you only need the event on one class if this event has to be only on one such element: 
`single_add_to_cart_button`
You can also just give a new class for the event so you dont have trouble finding it later. (refer naming convention docs for faster development)
Try this:

```
jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.ph_bookings_book_now_button:not(.disabled)").on("click", function() { ... });
```

Better way to write it is:

```
$(".yourElement:not(.disabled)").on('click', function { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you set id attribute to your button like

```
<button id="btn_abc" type="submit" name="add-to-cart" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt ph_bookings_book_now_button">Book Now</button>
```

and use id instead of class i.e

```
jQuery("btn_abc").on("click", function() {
    if(jQuery("#btn_abc").hasClass('disabled')) {
        break;
    } else {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
});
```

Thanks for letting us Help